# delete Not-Owned files in Android Q using Java code

Tags: java, android, delete-file, mediastore, android-10.0

How can we delete Not-Owned files  in Android Q

I dont want to use SAF file picker

can we trigger directly SAF to delete file

or is there a better sollution

I came across this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=  Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                    try {
                        String uri1 = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString();
                        String where = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID + "=?";
                        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(songforpopup._id)};
                        int deleted = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(uri1), where, selectionArgs);
                        Toast.makeText(AllSongsActivity.this, "" + deleted, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if (deleted>=0){
                            Toast.makeText(AllSongsActivity.this, "Succesfully deleted in Android Q",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                            RecoverableSecurityException recoverableSecurityException;
                            if (securityException instanceof RecoverableSecurityException) {
                                recoverableSecurityException =
                                        (RecoverableSecurityException)securityException;
                            } else {
                                throw new RuntimeException(
                                        securityException.getMessage(), securityException);
                            }
                            IntentSender intentSender =recoverableSecurityException.getUserAction()
                                    .getActionIntent().getIntentSender();
                            try {
                                startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender, DELETE_PERMISSION_REQUEST,
                                        null, 0, 0, 0, null);
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else {
                            throw new RuntimeException(
                                    securityException.getMessage(), securityException);
                        }
                    }

                    new AsyncListViewLoader().execute(Order);
                    timerDelayRunForScroll(100);
                }
```

but It doesn't delete the file and neither  does the security exception is thrown

Comment: You could actually do it with your IDE, just convert kotlin<->java option

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);

int deleted = context.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
```

Comment: but it doesnot physically delete the file from the device can we do that (file is on External SDCard)

Comment: Which Android version? On Q it should delete the file too. Below Q you should do it youirself indeed.

Comment: If it is not on removable micro SD card, then does it work then?

Comment: I am testing on an emulator Pixel XL Api 29

Comment: Yes. Ok. But why do you tell? I dont understand your reaction. On emulator you have both external memory and removable micro SD card. So you could answer my question i think.

Comment: I was replying to the Android version Question, the files are not deleted even from the folders on local storage

Comment: I tested on the same emulator.

Comment: I tried this solution and it works. In my experience, it is not possible to delete many files at once, because for each file the permission has to be set manually by the user. That should be better in Android R...I read somewhere, but don't know the source